# Is there an iOS program that performs multivariate linear regression?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, statistics

I'm looking for an iOS program that can calculate some statistics for me.

I want a program into which I can enter a bunch of observations, then the program uses multivariate linear regression (ordinary least squares) to find coefficients and standard errors for the line of best fit. I know of plenty of programs that do this on the Mac, but not any iOS programs.

There aren't any programs in the app store that list this as one of their key features, but I didn't know if it was an additional feature in something like Numbers. Alternately, while I'd prefer not a web app, that's certainly better than not having an app to do this. A web app that uses local storage so it can run even when offline would be best.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll comment this, as I have no idea what your question actually means, but isn't this something the Wolphram Alpha web page/iOS client App could do?  Happy to add as an answer if it is any good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think [Wolfram Alpha's main app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolframalpha/id334989259?mt=8) or their [Linear Algebra Course Assistant](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolfram-linear-algebra-course/id504401417?mt=8) are there yet with general multivariate linear regression but their email support is great and you might ask them which product of theirs might get that first. These do not run offline - so you may have to wait for the whole enchilada to arrive.

In the mean time, you will need to use something like [Matlab mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/matlab-mobile/id370976661?mt=8) to connect back to a computer that can actually run the numbers for you. This is a step better than just running screens as it lets you do input natively on iOS and shuttles forth and back the data to the main engine running remotely.

As you commented, you could get a matrix manipulation tool - both the [Linear Algebra Course Assistant](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wolfram-linear-algebra-course/id504401417?mt=8) and a few other apps like matrix calculator plus will invert matrices for you.

Comment: +1 Matlab mobile is really fun to use, but just as a *proof of concept*. :) The OSX GUI is much more efficient to me. I'm still waiting for solutions made specifically for the iPad.

Comment: Indeed - and with Siri and other server enabled apps (like movie and song streaming) - the line between iOS app that works with no network connection and ones that can do more with help from the data center is going to be a fertile ground for some amazing apps this year.

Comment: If the linear algebra course assistant can invert a matrix, it can get the coefficients easily enough: (X'X)^-1 X'Y gives the coefficient vector. That would be a good start.